# I want to know how to ask the user if he/she wants to continue using this program or terminate it using the do while loop?

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.*;

public class oddNumbers
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 System.out.println("enter two number");
 Scanner kb=new Scanner( System.in);
 int number=kb.nextInt();
 int number2=kb.nextInt();
do{ 
if(number%2!=0) { 
System.out.println(number); 
} 
number++; 
} while( number< number2);

}
}
```

### Heading

I want  to know how to ask the user if  he/she wants to continue using  this program or  terminate it, and  them  this program has to do what the user wants to do.  I  have use the do while loop for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put your code within another do while loop.

Here is your solution

```
public class oddNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("enter two number");
            int number = kb.nextInt();
            int number2 = kb.nextInt();
            do {
                if (number % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.println(number);
                }
                number++;
            } while (number < number2);

            System.out.println("You want to continue : (Y/N) ");
        } while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(kb.next().trim()));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask them to input a specific number to exit, like -1, or a character like 'q', then just `break` out of your loop.

I would just add a higher level menu:

```
Please choose:

[B]egin // prompt for numbers
[Q]uit // `break` out of your loop
```